# Can I add a value to all members of an Array

Tags: c++, stl

Is there an algorithm in STL that can add at once the same value to all the members of an array?

For example:

```
KnightMoves moveKnight(int currentPossition_x, int currentPossition_y)
{
    array<int , 8> possibleMoves_x = { -2 , -2 , -1 , -1 ,  1 , 1 , 2 ,  2 };
    array<int , 8> possibleMoves_y = { -1 ,  1 , -2 ,  2 , -2 , 2 , -1 , 1 };

    for (auto it = possibleMoves_x.begin(); it != possibleMoves_x.end(); it++)
    {
        array <int, 8> newTempKnightPoss_x = currentPossition_x + possibleMoves_x;

        array <int, 8> newTempKnightPoss_y = currentPossition_y + possibleMoves_x;
    }

}
```

I could do something like this but i was hopping there is a better solution

```
KnightMoves moveKnight(int currentPossition_x, int currentPossition_y)
{
   array<int , 8> possibleMoves_x = { -2 , -2 , -1 , -1 ,  1 , 1 , 2 ,  2 };
   array<int , 8> possibleMoves_y = { -1 ,  1 , -2 ,  2 , -2 , 2 , -1 , 1 };

   for (auto it = possibleMoves_x.begin(); it != possibleMoves_x.end(); it++)
   {
       *it = *it  +currentPossition_x;

   }
   for (auto it = possibleMoves_y.begin(); it != possibleMoves_y.end(); it++)
   {
       *it = *it + currentPossition_y;

   }
}
```

The axpepted results are 2 arrays which each element is the element plus a constant value;

Comment: Depending on what all you want to do, there is [`std::valarray`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray)

Comment: Use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a suitable and simple [lambda function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (or functor object)?

Comment: for range makes it trivial though: `for (auto& e : possibleMoves_x)
   {
       e += currentPossition_x;
   }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have C++11 you can use the [range-based-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop:

```
KnightMoves moveKnight(int currentPossition_x, int currentPossition_y){
    array<int , 8> possibleMoves_x = { -2 , -2 , -1 , -1 ,  1 , 1 , 2 ,  2 };
    array<int , 8> possibleMoves_y = { -1 ,  1 , -2 ,  2 , -2 , 2 , -1 , 1 };

    for(auto& i : possibleMoves_x){ i += currentPossition_x; }
    for(auto& i : possibleMoves_y){ i += currentPossition_y; }
}
```

Before C++11 you can use [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):

```
struct adder{
    adder(int val): v{val}{}
    void operator()(int& n) { n += v; }
    int v;
};

KnightMoves moveKnight(int currentPossition_x, int currentPossition_y){
    array<int , 8> possibleMoves_x = { -2 , -2 , -1 , -1 ,  1 , 1 , 2 ,  2 };
    array<int , 8> possibleMoves_y = { -1 ,  1 , -2 ,  2 , -2 , 2 , -1 , 1 };

    std::for_each(possibleMoves_x.begin(), possibleMoves_x.end(), 
                  adder(currentPossition_x));
    std::for_each(possibleMoves_y.begin(), possibleMoves_y.end(),
                  adder(currentPossition_x));
}
```

Comment: "before C++11" you cannot use lambdas.