# Add number on memcpy

Tags: c++

When I use a memcpy I copy the content of one table into another. I give the address of my first table, then my second, then the size I want to copy.  So I think that's is not possible to make an addition of a number and a adress.

I would like to know if it is possible to do this by adding an addition to the table to be copied.

I would like something like that:

```
int *a = return_number(); // in A i will have following number {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
int *b;
memcpy(b, a + 2, 8); // I would like that B is equal to {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

I tried to make my own memcpy but that's not the point. I would like to gain performance so i wanna know if it's possible to make something like this with a memcpy or another standard lib function ?

Thanks for your answer,

Comment: You don't really want to copy **memory**, you want to copy **objects** (i.e. memory with some specific meaning stored in it). And you don't just want to copy the objects, you want to [**`std::transform`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) them!

Comment: And you don't want pointers to dynamically allocated memory (which I hope you have) but `std::vector`.

Comment: Also, instead of `std::transform` you could use a very simple [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: Lastly, this question is *very* similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811251/can-i-add-a-value-to-all-members-of-an-array) posted just yesterday.

Comment: Yes! Why don't you compile and test it.